# Conditional label colors in MAUI XAML

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a StackLayout that binds to a list and I would like to put each item's `Text` property in a label, with different colors based on the `IsSpecial` property in the following manner:

```xml
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor= "Red if IsSpecial otherwise White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

I tried using triggers but I couldn't figure out how to reference the target type properly.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, e.g. the model class that you're binding to. Where is this `IsSpecial` property defined and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not showing the model class you're binding to, I'll make an educated guess:

```cs
public class Line
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

or something like *(if the values keep changing)*:

```cs
public partial class Line : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _text;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isSpecial;
}
```

Then you can use a [DataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-8.0#data-triggers) like this:

```xml
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Line">
            <Label
                Text="{Binding Text}"
                TextColor="White">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        TargetType="Label"
                        Binding="{Binding IsSpecial}"
                        Value="True">
                        <Setter
                            Property="TextColor"
                            Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

*Note that I've also added the `x:DataType` attribute to enable compiled bindings. That way, the binding expressions get evaluated during compile-time.*